# It seems my server is responding with html or css page instead of JSON

Tags: java, php, android, json

I am developing an android app in which the maing page,main activity (MainActivity.java) contains 8 buttons. Clicking on any button leads me to my next activity i.e payment activity(PaymentActivity.java). Payment activity is to verify my user with correct account no and password from the database I have created in MySQL (My table column names are-1 accno and 2 bpassword) under webhost free hosting. For connecting to the webhost server for which I am using PHP scripts. When I enter account no and password already stored in my MySQL database and click on the button "Pay" then it should be verifiying it with the MySQL database on server side and show a toast that "Payment Successful"..now when I am running this app in the emulator...after processing till "Checking network-Loading", "Contacting servers-checking credentials" (please see PaymentActivity.java code for this), but after this its showing me "Unfortunatly buttonphp(my appname) has stopped". I am posting my entire android code here. Please help me with this by specifying my errors and advise me the correct code to fix that error. Any help, advice or suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance !

PaymentActivity.java

```
package com.example.buttonphp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.buttonphp.library.DatabaseHandler;
import com.example.buttonphp.library.UserFunctions;


public class PaymentActivity extends Activity {

Button button1;
EditText inputAccno;
EditText inputPassword;
private TextView loginErrorMsg;

// JSON Response node names
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
private static String KEY_ACCOUNTNO = "accno";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment);

// Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
inputAccno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.accountno);
inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);



button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {

if (  ( !inputAccno.getText().toString().equals("")) && 
(!inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) )
         {
             NetAsync(view);
         }
else if ( ( !inputAccno.getText().toString().equals("")) )
         {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                     "Password field empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
else if ( ( !inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) )
         {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                     "Account no field empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
else
         {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
             "Account no and Password fields are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
     }
 });

}

/**
 * Async Task to check whether internet connection is working.
**/

 private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String,String,Boolean>
 {
    private ProgressDialog nDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        nDialog = new ProgressDialog(PaymentActivity.this);
        nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
        nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
        nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        nDialog.setCancelable(true);
        nDialog.show();
    }

/**
* Gets current device state and checks for working internet connection by trying Google.
    **/


//     private ProgressDialog nDialog;


 @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args){



 ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
  getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
   if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
      try {
           URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
           HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                urlc.connect();
                if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    return true;
                }
          } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return false;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th){

        if(th == true){
            nDialog.dismiss();
            new ProcessPayment().execute();
        }
        else{
            nDialog.dismiss();
            loginErrorMsg.setText(" Error in Network Connection");
        }
    }


}

/**
 * Async Task to get and send data to My Sql database through JSON respone.
 **/
private class ProcessPayment extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {


    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    String accno,bpassword;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        inputAccno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.accountno);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        accno = inputAccno.getText().toString();
        bpassword = inputPassword.getText().toString();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(PaymentActivity.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
        pDialog.setMessage("Checking credentials ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = userFunction.paymentUser(accno, bpassword);
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        try {
           if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {

                String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

                if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                    pDialog.setMessage("Payment in process");
                    //pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
             DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                    JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");


        /**
        *If JSON array details are stored in SQlite it launches the User Panel.
        **/
        Intent back = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        back.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    startActivity(back);
                    /**
                     * Close Login Screen
                     **/
                    finish();
                }else{

                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect account no / password");
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
}
public void NetAsync(View view){
    new NetCheck().execute();
}
}
```

My JSONParser.java file

```
package com.example.buttonphp.library;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

Logcat error :

```
03-05 19:47:50.940: D/dalvikvm(2103): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 48K, 4% free 3228K/3352K,paused 
160ms, total 161ms
03-05 19:47:51.840: D/gralloc_goldfish(2103): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
03-05 19:47:58.500: I/Choreographer(2103): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be    
doing too much work on its main thread.
03-05 19:48:02.660: I/Choreographer(2103): Skipped 773 frames!  The application may be 
doing too much work on its main thread.
03-05 19:48:04.660: I/Choreographer(2103): Skipped 130 frames!  The application may be 
doing too much work on its main thread.
03-05 19:48:22.660: D/dalvikvm(2103): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 141K, 6% free 3600K/3816K,   
paused 56ms, total 64ms
03-05 19:48:22.870: D/dalvikvm(2103): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 60K, 7% free 3620K/3872K,  
paused 54ms, total 57ms
03-05 19:48:22.890: I/dalvikvm-heap(2103): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.212MB for 635812 
byte allocation
03-05 19:48:23.040: D/dalvikvm(2103): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 4240K/4496K, 
paused 144ms, total 144ms
03-05 19:49:56.120: D/dalvikvm(2103): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 319K, 9% free 4424K/4820K, 
paused 157ms, total 707ms
03-05 19:51:33.500: I/Choreographer(2103): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be 
doing too much work on its main thread.
03-05 19:51:34.370: W/InputEventReceiver(2103): Attempted to finish an input event but 
the input event receiver has already been disposed.
03-05 19:51:34.370: I/Choreographer(2103): Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be                        
doing too much work on its main thread.
03-05 19:51:34.990: I/Choreographer(2103): Skipped 154 frames!  The application may be 
doing too much work on its main thread.
03-05 19:51:37.200: I/Choreographer(2103): Skipped 78 frames!  The application may be 
doing too much work on its main thread.
03-05 19:51:37.880: I/Choreographer(2103): Skipped 65 frames!  The application may be 
doing too much work on its main thread.
03-05 19:51:41.090: I/Choreographer(2103): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be 
03-05 19:51:41.140: E/JSON(2103): <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2      
Final//EN">n<html>n <head>n  <title>Index of /payment</title>n </head>n <body>n<h1>Index        
of /payment</h1>n<ul><li><a href="/"> Parent Directory</a></li>n<li><a href="includep/">   
includep/</a></li>n<li><a href="indexp.php"> indexp.php</a></li>n</ul>n</body></html>n
03-05 19:51:41.200: E/JSON Parser(2103): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException:       
Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
03-05 19:51:41.330: I/Choreographer(2103): Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be   
doing too much work on its main thread.
03-05 19:51:41.470: D/AndroidRuntime(2103): Shutting down VM
03-05 19:51:41.480: W/dalvikvm(2103): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception   
(group=0xb3a49b90)
03-05 19:51:41.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2103): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 19:51:41.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2103): Process: com.example.buttonphp, PID: 2103
03-05 19:51:41.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2103): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-05 19:51:41.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2103): at com.example.buttonphp.PaymentActivity                        
$ProcessPayment.onPostExecute(PaymentActivity.java:191)
03-05 19:51:41.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2103): at com.example.buttonphp.PaymentActivity    
$ProcessPayment.onPostExecute(PaymentActivity.java:1)
03-05 19:51:41.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2103): at 
android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
03-05 19:51:41.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2103): at 
android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
03-05 19:51:41.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2103): at 
android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage    (AsyncTask.java:645)
03-05 19:51:41.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2103): at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-05 19:51:41.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2103): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-05 19:51:41.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2103): at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
03-05 19:51:41.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2103): at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 19:51:41.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2103): at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-05 19:51:41.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2103): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit    
$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
03-05 19:51:41.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2103): at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
03-05 19:51:41.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2103): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native 
Method)
03-05 19:51:45.450: D/dalvikvm(2103): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 401K, 10% free 4573K/5052K, 
paused 324ms,total 324ms
```

Comment: This is a lot of code to analyze... try to paste just the RELEVANT code please.

Comment: Add logcat with error part when your application stops. Also you may want to use header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); before echo json_encode($response);

Comment: @Merlevede-The main code is PaymentActivity.java file in which I hv written connectivity.

Comment: @Merlevede - here is the edited code. Thank you.

Comment: @albertsmuktupavels- here is the edited code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what your server returns formatted.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Index of /payment</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Index of /payment</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/"> Parent Directory</a></li>
            <li><a href="includep/">includep/</a></li>
            <li><a href="indexp.php"> indexp.php</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

So this is a server side problem.

Before trying to use your web service in an environment, like android, try it using a tool specially developed for testing purposes, like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) for chrome.